# Deleting Pushed Data From Firebase - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-deployment

Im creating a membership website (web app) for a university project which im jusing firebase for my database. I've come across a challening of deleting data from the firebaase. So to dive right in:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {
// User is signed in.
//Set Variables
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("users").child(user.uid);

ref.child("rentingAddresses").on("child_added", function(data){
    //Set Local Variables
    var firstLine = data.child("firstLine").val();
    var secondLine = data.child("secondLine").val();
    var thirdLine = data.child("thirdLine").val();
    var town = data.child("town").val();
    var city = data.child("city").val();
    var county = data.child("county").val();
    var postcode = data.child("postcode").val();
    var status = data.child("propertyStatus").val();
    var i;
    var title = '';
    var address = [firstLine, secondLine, thirdLine, town, city, postcode];
    var maxFields = 100;
    //for loop to loop through array
    for(i = 0; i < address.length; i++){
        //if array value is empty move to the next value
        if(address[i] == ''){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            //if at the end of the array
            if(i == address.length - 1){
                title += address[i].toUpperCase();
            }
            else{
                title += address[i].toUpperCase() + ", ";
            } 
        }   
    }
    //add values of array to (address) to title heading
        var appendAddress = "<div class='personal-details'><div class='details-container' style='margin-left: 20px'><h2 id='address-title' class='info-title'>" + title + "</h2><div class='profile-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' type='submit' id='' onclick='removeProperty()'>Remove Property</button><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' type='submit' id='' onclick=''>Go To Property</button></div></div></div>";
        $('#page-content').append(appendAddress);

}, function(error){
    //error message
    console.log("Error: Couldnt Load Address");
});
} else {
// No user is signed in.
}
});
```

The code above goes though all the data of the child (rentingAddresses) and stores them into the vairable. I then sore the variables into an array and loop though them to remove the empty ('') variables. I then store all the vairable into another and append it with other code to the webpage.

My problem is I cant find a way to delete the data from the database.

What I am trying to do is, provide the user with a button to delete the address. When they click the button it'll delete the address from the database resuting in deleting it from the webpage aswell.

I have tried so many way and just cant seem to find a solution.

firebase Structure:

```
ref
--users
---userUID
----rentingAddresses
-----pushKey
------firstLine
------secondLine
------thirdLine
------town
------city
------county
------postcode
-----pushKey
and so on
```

Please can someone help, give me advice of what im may be doing wrong and a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to delete a specific line in the address or the entire address as whole?

Comment: The entire address under the push key. So the address will show on the webpage. There’s a button underneath with an option to delete the address. When clicked it willl delete the entire address from the database